# SignalR hub.on method is not firing in Android

Tags: android, signalr

I m trying to implement SignalR client in Android application. but hub.on ("method name") is not firing.

```
Platform.loadPlatformComponent( new AndroidPlatformComponent() );
String host = "...";
String qs = "....";
HubConnection connection = new HubConnection(...);
HubProxy hub = connection.createHubProxy( ... );
```

I have tried following 2 options to subscribe

Option 1

```
hub.on( “testMessage”, new SubscriptionHandler1< CustomMessage >() {
    @Override
    public void run(CustomMessage msg) {

        Log.d(“result := “, msg.text);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg.text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}, CustomMessage.class);
```

Option 2

```
....
hub.subscribe(“testMessage”);
....
Handler handler = new Handler();

public void addMessage( CustomMessage msg ) {

    final String fStatus = msg.text;
    handler.post(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, fStatus, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    });
}
```

I m getting following logger messages

```
Verbose – serverSentEvents – Found new data:data: {}
Verbose – serverSentEvents – Trigger onData: {}
Verbose – HubConnection – Received data;
```

Comment: I presume you got your connection up and running: i.e. did you call `connection.start()`, and `.get()` [as described in my blog post](http://whathecode.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/getting-started-with-the-java-signalr-sdk/), and no exceptions were thrown during this execution?

Comment: @Soney Antony Have you solved it?

Comment: Its working fine with http://signalrcalc.apphb.com But its not working with our server. Debugging in our server. Hope issue may be with server side

Comment: @SoneyAntony So it _is_ a connection problem then, correct?

Comment: P.s. I rolled back to your previous post. Rather than updating your question effectively removing the question from the 'question', post an answer yourself outlining what was going wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: The issue is because the query string format. Now I m using "username=aaa&password=12323". ITs working fine Thanks for the support

Comment: @StevenJeuris I have a similar issue in SignalR Android. Could you please have a look and help me out? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264835/setting-up-signal-r-in-android-crash-issue

Comment: I came up with a similar issue and I followed your awesome guide Steven. Can you help me out? @StevenJeuris http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264835/setting-up-signal-r-in-android-crash-issue

Comment: @SoneyAntony I faced a similar issue. Can you help me out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35264835/setting-up-signal-r-in-android-crash-issue