# Setting up Signal R in Android: Crash/Hung Issue

Tags: android, signalr, azure-mobile-services, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I followed [THIS tutorial](https://whathecode.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/getting-started-with-the-java-signalr-sdk/) to set up a .NET Backend for my Android app to implement Signal R. I set up a SignalR Self-Hosted backend.

**Here's my Backend Code in a Console Project:**

```
namespace SignalRSelfHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // This will *ONLY* bind to localhost, if you want to bind to all addresses
            // use http://*:8080 to bind to all addresses. 
            // See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx 
            // for more information.
            string url = "http://localhost:8080";
            using (WebApp.Start(url))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
    class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
    public class MessageHub : Hub
    {
        public static event Action<string, string> MessageReceived = delegate { };

        public void SendMessage(string name, string message)
        {
            MessageReceived(name, message);
        }

    }

    public class CustomType
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Id;
    }
}
```

**My Android Code:**

```
    Handler handler;
    TextView statusField;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        handler = new Handler();
        statusField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusField);

        Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());
        // Change to the IP address and matching port of your SignalR server.
        String host = "http://192.168.1.5:8080/";
        HubConnection connection = new HubConnection( host );
        HubProxy hub = connection.createHubProxy( "MessageHub" );
        ClientTransport transport = new ServerSentEventsTransport(connection.getLogger());

        SignalRFuture<Void> awaitConnection = connection.start(transport);
        try {
            awaitConnection.get();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.d("CHECK", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            Log.d("CHECK", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        hub.subscribe(this);

        try {
            hub.invoke( "SendMessage", "Client", "Hello world!" ).get();
            hub.invoke( "SendCustomType",
                    new CustomType() {{ Name = "Universe"; Id = 42; }} ).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // Handle ...
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // Handle ...
        }

    }

    public void UpdateStatus(String status) {
        final String fStatus = status;
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                statusField.setText(fStatus);
            }
        });
    }

    public class CustomType
    {
        public String Name;
        public int Id;
    }
```

However, I end up with a screen that hangs and it displays nothing and the app stops responding. The android logger displays the following error:

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException:
>   failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 80) after 15000ms:
>   isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Is my code correct and have I followed the guide properly? It's a very straight forward guide but this issue comes up. Can someone help out?

**EDIT**:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621657/implementing-signal-r-in-android) is a very similar Question, in fact it describes the same issue. However it didn't do me any good. If you notice my android code, I've already made those changes proposed in that question. Still didn't rectify the issue.

**Stacktrace**

```
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to / 192.168.1.5(port 8080) after 15000ms
 at microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.SignalRFuture.get(SignalRFuture.java: 112)
 at microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.SignalRFuture.get(SignalRFuture.java: 102)
 at com.example.dinuka.signalrtest.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java: 40)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java: 6289)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java: 1119)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2655)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 2767)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java: 177)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java: 1449)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java: 102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java: 145)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 5951)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java: 372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java: 1400)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java: 1195)
 Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to / 192.168.1.5(port 8080) after 15000ms
 at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java: 169)
 at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java: 122)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java: 183)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java: 456)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java: 882)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java: 139)
 at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java: 1194)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java: 392)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java: 295)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java: 373)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java: 323)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java: 491)
 at microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.http.java.NetworkRunnable.run(NetworkRunnable.java: 72)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java: 818)
```

Comment: show the full logcat..

Comment: Hold on @MurtazaKhursheedHussain

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain Edited. Sorry I couldn't properly Format the code.

Comment: Is your Android device connected to the same network as your server? 192.168.1.5 is a local network address that won't be available over the Internet.

Comment: I am hosting the server from my laptop and connected to the same wifi my phone is connected to. Am I doing a silly mistake here? :D @RicardoLage

Comment: The error suggests a network issue, not something on your code. Try accessing this address from a browser on your phone.

Comment: I got a blank page when I accessed '192.168.1.5' though Chrome Android. What does that say? @RicardoLage Is there something I should be seeing? The page keeps on loading when I go to 192.168.1.5:8080 via mobile chrome and then displays 'Webpage not available'

Comment: Not sure what you should be seeing. Depends on your server. There seems to be an issue with the signalr client library though. See here if one of the suggestions there help you: https://github.com/SignalR/java-client/issues/63

Comment: I think its due to cross-domain issue

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain Really? Do you know the fix?

Comment: If your issue has not been solved, IMO, you can refer my sample code at https://github.com/ngocchung/SimpleSignalRClient. Server side app: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Comment: @BNK Damn that looks solid! I will try it today. Thanks man

Comment: @BNK Btw how can I replace the IP Address with the URL to my backend? For example the base URL of my web service is "https://my_service.azuremobile.net". I've seen that people add the part '/signalr' to the end of the URL. Can you explain that a bit please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue a few days ago and this Github issue helped:
https://github.com/SignalR/java-client/issues/63

Basically what I did was modify the WebsocketTransport.java in the signalr-client-sdk project. Replace:

```
uri = new URI(url);
```

with

```
uri = new URI(url.replace("http://", "ws://"));
```

around line 86 in the source code.

I can now connect and send message and recieve raw data but cannot subscribe to events...

Hope this helps you get passed your problem.

Comment: I will surely try this out tomorrow. Can't wait! Thank you. I will get back to you tomorrow. It's such a pity that there aren't any good tutorials out there. So hard to set this up properly

Comment: Hey could you please send me the JAR files? I think mine are mighty old. Can you send them to me?

Comment: Having so much difficulty trying to package the JAR files from the SignalR project on github

Comment: Sorry, was with out internet. Do you still need the jars?

Comment: Yes sir that would be great! :) Can you dropbox them maybe? My Jars are outdated.

Comment: Here it is. Please note I'm including Jars I found googling (built 2014) and the ones I built. Also note that the signalr-client-sdk-android-* are .aar files (Android Binary Library) to be referenced by your project. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xcccz4gwjnxuiz8/AAClkwO_6KrbbyMclgD2ae_pa?dl=0